# Is there any way to access the storage of another pallet in Substrate-based blockchain?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, storage, nft

I'm trying to transfer the collection ID from relay chain to a parachain. I am currently accessing the `collectionId` from its storage, and I am wondering if there's a way to access the storage of the `pallet_nft` on another chain in order to facilitate the transfer.

Answer (score 2):

Between two pallets in the same chain you need [coupling](https://docs.substrate.io/build/pallet-coupling/) between them to access the storage. An example about this in the Substrate FRAME repository is  between pallets [bounties](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/bounties) and [child-bounties](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/child-bounties) which are tightly coupled.

See this specific example where in [pallet child-bounties access](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/child-bounties/src/lib.rs#L820C3-L821C46) the [storage of pallet bounties](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/bounties/src/lib.rs#L303).

```rs
let parent_bounty = pallet_bounties::Pallet::<T>::bounties(bounty_id)
            .ok_or(BountiesError::<T>::InvalidIndex)?;
```

To query another pallet storage from another chain you have to construct an XCM call using the instruction Transact. It has been proposed by the main XCM ideologues on a previous StackExchange question: [XCM Transact for interfaces](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2160/2762) and in this Post on the Polkadot Forum: [XCM Storage Query](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/xcm-storage-query/633/2?u=alexd10s).

You can find a similar example about what you achieve in the [XCM docs Examples](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/blob/main/examples/src/3_transact/mod.rs).